OData 8 with .NET Core 8 Select and Expand Failure
Get request error :

Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectAllAndExpand1[Core.Objects.Result1[Core.Entities.Invoice]]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[Core.Objects.Result`1[Core.Entities.Invoice]]'

Solution :
I found reason that this error occurred and I corrected it. In OData, if you register EnableQuery globally like this
Services 
     .AddMvc() 
     .AddControllers() 
     .AddOData(options => options.AddRouteComponents("odata", OdataBuilder.GetEdmModel()) 
                                 .EnableQueryFeatures(null))
     .AddODataNewtonsoftJson();

you must not use EnableQuery annotation on a method.
Before:
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var Items = _unitOfWork.Set<TEntity>();
    return Ok(Items);
}

After:
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var Items = _unitOfWork.Set<TEntity>();
    return Ok(Items);
} 

Removing the [EnableQuery] fixed the problem.
